# Is there a simple way to traverse a multi-dimensional array and transform each element in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

If I have an multi-dimensional array of latitudes and longitudes like:

```
let inputLatLongArray = [[[
  ["-100.7777777775", "99.2222222"],
  ["-100.777777777", "87.2222222"],
  ["-100.777777777",  "34.2222222"],
  ["-100.777777777", "99.2222222"],
  ["-100.777777777", "99.2222222"]
 ]]]
```

How can I traverse & transform the elements so each nested lat/long only has 2 decimal places?

Expected output:

```
let expectedLatLongArray = [[[
  ["-100.77", "99.22"],      
  ["-100.77", "87.22"], 
  ["-100.77", "34.22"], 
  ["-100.77", "99.22"], 
  ["-100.77", "99.22"]
 ]]]
```

Code:

Here's what I have so far below. My thought was to use a flatMap and then map down into the nested arrays but this doesn't seem correct either. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
func roundLatAndLong(with latLongArray: [[[[String, String]]]]) -> [[[[String, String]]]] {
    let coordinates = latLongArray.flatMap { $0 }.map({ $0 }).map({ //Rounded both array positions down to 2 decimal places })
   return coordinates
}

func rounded(toDecimalPlaces n: Int) -> String {
  return String(format: "%.\(n)f", self)
}
```

Comment: Nested arrays are a really bad way to store anything. I suggest rethinking everything about your data model! For example if you've got a pair of doubles representing latitudes and longitudes, make a Coordinate struct with `latitude` and `longitude` properties. And so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it is handed to me.

Comment: That’s not how programming works. Nothing is written on tablets of jade.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question. Three high-reputation members of the community have taken the time and trouble to answer your question, and it is highly disrespectful to then vandalise the question and render their answers obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

If your data type is Double, there is no such thing as having a number of decimal places. If you try to round a value to a given number of decimal places, you'll get a value close to, but not exactly, that value. That's because binary floating point can't represent most decimal values exactly. If you really want to convert your values to values with an exact number of decimal places, you should use the `Decimal` type.

You COULD convert your array of lat/long Double values to Strings with a given number of decimal places pretty easily.

If you had an array of structs containing lat/longs, or an array of tuples, it would be a lot cleaner. Or even an array of dictionaries with keys of "lat" and "long"

Comment: Whenever you deserialize them you mean? (Convert them from JSON to objects?)

Comment: @LocalSwiftGuy why do you need to discard the fraction digits? You can simply format them when displaying it

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Instead of storing as string store it as a Double

Comment: There is no such thing as a binary floating point number with a specific number of decimal places. That is not how binary floating point works. You need to either save your values as strings in Core Data, or save them in Core Data as doubles and format them to the desired number of places for display.

Comment: This seems like a comment not an answer. But no way I’m flagging it. Answerer has god-like reputation. I don’t see where op ever mentions using double. Perhaps it’s a bad question and so one can post a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```swift
func nestedTransform<InElement, OutElement>(nested: [[[[InElement]]]], transform: (InElement) -> OutElement) -> [[[[OutElement]]]]
{
    return nested.map {$0.map { $0.map { $0.map(transform) }}}
}
```

I think in your attempt you just had your nesting a little off, that is you were chaining instead of nesting the `map` calls.

You would use this like this:

```swift
let roundedResult = nestedTransform(nested: inputLatLongArray) { $0.rounded(toDecimalPlaces: 8) }
```

Assuming the existence to a suitable extension on `InElement`. You edited the question to remove the original `Double` array. So this answer serves to solve the mapping of nested arrays. The implementation of the transform is left up to you!

I also strongly encourage you to read the answer by @DuncanC and the comments by @LeoDaubus about why your original transform is ill-advised.

Answer (score 2):

You can gradually extend `Array` to allow transformations on multi-dimensional ones:

```swift
extension Array {
    func map2<T, U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> [[U]] where Element == [T] {
        map { $0.map(transform) }
    }
    
    func map3<T,U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> [[[U]]] where Element == [[T]] {
        map { $0.map2(transform) }
    }
    
    func map4<T,U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> [[[[U]]]] where Element == [[[T]]] {
        map { $0.map3(transform) }
    }
}
```

You can then use the extension like this:

```
let inputLatLongArray = [[[
    ["-98.73264361706984", "38.5447223260328"],
    ["-98.73255257987707", "38.543630550793544"],
    ["-98.7302159585956",  "38.54506646913993"],
    ["-98.73200635672036", "38.54556488037536"],
    ["-98.73264361706984", "38.5447223260328"]
]]]
let transform: (String) -> String = {
    return String(format: "%.\(8)f", Double($0) ?? 0.0)
}
let transformedArray = inputLatLongArray.map4(transform)
print(transformedArray)
```

Comment: It looks to me that all elements are in a single collection of collections of 2 elements. I would just join it twice and map the third into a tuple of two doubles. Then OP would be able to map the latitude and longitude into CLLocationCoordinate2D if needed.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to reduce the precision of the latitude and longitude. OP should store it as a Double and format it just when displaying it. `let coordinates = inputLatLongArray.joined().joined().map { (Double($0[0])!, Double($0[1])!) }`
`for coordinate in coordinates.map(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init) {` `print(coordinate)`
`}`

Comment: I would also mention that `[[[[String, String]]]]` it is not a valid type

Comment: @LeoDabus valid points, feel free to add an answer with those details. In the end the asker should be able to pick the best solution that suits their needs, so the more solutions the better for him :)